# How to check if someone is on Google+ by email address?

Tags: google-plus

We're trying to get some Google reviews for a company by contacting their past clients and asking them to leave reviews. The process is substantially easier if they already have a Google+ account. Is there an easy way to search by email to see if they have an account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [Google Contacts](https://www.google.com/contacts/) (or through [Gmail Contacts](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?tab=Cm#contacts)) the user information will show a "Connected Profile" if they're on Google+.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I looked both in the Gmail API and Google+ API and didn't seem to find something.

But I remember working with the Google Apps for Business Contacts API and remembered that if I added to the contacts using the API, and added just the email addresses Google Apps filled the photo and the name for those that had Google+ accounts, maybe you can start from there.

Answer (score -1):

I found this tip. The concept is sound.

We are planning to use this.

http://eran.sandler.co.il/2011/07/17/determine-if-an-email-address-is-gmail-or-hosted-gmail-google-apps-for-your-domain/

Comment: Could you please add the steps required, or at least a summary? Link-only answers aren't very helpful.